# how to find MST after add new node?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree

How we find `MST (Minimum Spanning Tree)` after add new node or change distance of ways?

I need help to solve this. Can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When **adding** new edges:

You will need to perform a graph traversal, the easiest is DFS for this, from one of the sides of the modified/new edge. If you can back to a node you were to before, you have a cycle.

In that cycle, you will need to remove the largest edge. You will get a tree again, and it is the minimal spanning one.

If you are **changing** edge weights, you will need to:

- Disconnect the graph into 2 components, A and B, by temporarily removing the new edge.
- If the new edge has a smaller weight than before, you can put it back in. Otherwise:
- Iterate through edges that you have processed before, and check if they join A to B.
- Pick the smallest edge from those, and connect the components using that edge.

Again, you get a new minimal spanning tree.

Overall, this is `O(V+E)`, times a small factor of inverse Ackermann.

Comment: What ensures that this new tree (when adding new edges) still is a minimal spanning tree?

Comment: Is there any linear way to add a **node** (with how many edges it can)?